# Where is the best Way to calculate result in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, db2

I search the best practise to improve us applications in the MODEL (on MCV pattern)

For agregate few datas, we can procced on the SQL request OR on the MODEL.

**Ex: agregate data on SQL (my agregateresult is on alias :  result_year)**

```
SELECT
  id AS product_id,
  name AS product_name,
  ISNULL(quantity_january, 0) + ISNULL(quantity_february, 0) + ISNULL(quantity_march, 0) as result_year
FROM
  product_sale
```

My model can be definied like that (phpfriendly):

```
class productResult{
    // define one var by sql column.
    $this->resultYear = null;

    function productResult(){
        //here I make the link between SQL and PHP.
    }

    // define function for get the sql result.
    public function getResultYear(){
        return $this->resultYear;
    }
}

// I get just the my result.
$productResult->getResultYear();
```

Or I want to procedd with other method:

**Ex: get all data from my SQL and agregate on the model (in the function get my value)**

```
SELECT
  id AS product_id,
  name AS product_name,
  quantity_january,
  quantity_february
  quantity_march
FROM
  product_sale


class productResult{
    // define one var by sql column.
    $this->quantityJanuary= null;
    $this->quantityFebruary= null;
    $this->quantityMarch= null;

    function productResult(){
        //here I make the link between SQL and PHP.
    }

    // define function for get the sql result.
    public function getResultYear(){
        return $this->quantityJanuary
             +$this->quantityFebruary
             +$this->quantityMarch;
    }
}
// I get just my resulyt.
$productResult->getResultYear();
```

This code is just **for explain my problem** : I search where is **the best way** to create my application...

- Is SQL is always faster than the model (PHP or other language) for agregate data?
- In what cases can the calculation in the model (PHP or other) to be better than SQL?
- Is there any good practice to recover its SQL as a model?

PS: It's not a question with a PHP TAG because it's not a question about a PHP , but about a SQL in the model on all language (PHP/JAVA/ASP/C# ... etc...).

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Generally SQL is designed to operate very well on aggregate data.

Additionally the network is less used if you pass only the aggregate data instead of all the data to build your aggregates.

So if possible leave the sql engine to aggregate your data and extract them as aggregated. Instead if you already have all the data in memory on your application server (java, php, or what else) you can aggregate the data directly on memory.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your respone! Do you know if exist a website for explain all this rules? (I don't know we can agregate all data on memory? )